# how to make user controls transparent

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, transparency

I have migrated a userControl from vb6 to vb.net, and i have problem with it's transparency.
in vb6, the property backstyle was used to make the control transparent, but in vb.net, i can't find it.
is there any equivalent for this property?

Comment: does setting the BackColor to Transparent do what you want?

Comment: wpf? winforms? web? if it's winforms, [this link might help.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk5b13s4(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Plutonix, i already try backcolor to transparent but it doesn't resolve the problem

Comment: Zohar Peled , it s winforms

Comment: i tried SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, True) with backcolor= transparent as the link say but i have white rectangle.             précision: my usercontrol is rectangle witch dimensions changes when i draw it (it's for selection by rectangle),

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some searches on the internet I found this pearl:

```
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
    Get
        ' Make background transparent
        Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or &H20
        Return cp
    End Get
End Property

Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(e As PaintEventArgs)
    '' call MyBase.OnPaintBackground(e) only if the backColor is not Color.Transparent
    If Me.BackColor <> Color.Transparent Then
        MyBase.OnPaintBackground(e)
    End If
End Sub
```

I've tested it and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: sorry but i dont understand, would you please explain more?

Comment: just put the code snippet in your user control and it should make it transparent, when the `BackColor` property is set to `Color.Transparent`. the `CreateParams` override allows for transparent background, and the `OnPaintBackground` override is pretty self explanatory...

Answer (score 0):

Just an observation: when we set CreateParams.ExStyle to &H20, so we allocate a unique device context for each window in the class, I noticed that if these User controls are stacked, they reverse their display order. Thus, if we Bring to Front a user control, instead of painting last, as controls normally do, it paints first, displaying behind all other controls, being inserted at the base of the display stack, not at its top (to display last). Likewise, if we Send to Back, it ends up painting last, displaying top-most, because it is actually put at the top of the display list, not at its start. It is because, with this flag set, they are ordered in the display stack in that reversed order. Once we wrap our heads around that and know it will happen, we can manage OK.