# Adding Click Event to AxVlc Control?

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent, libvlc

I am trying to make a program which plays video and receives user input on specific frames. i need to make a click event for the axvlc video player. Is this possible?

my program contains an instance of the VLC ActiveX Plugin in a windows form in visual studios.
I want, while the program is paused, for the user to be able to single click a point on the frame, trigger an event, add the location of the mouse to a list.

otherwise, i have considered rendering a bitmap of whatever frame it is on while paused so that i can add click events to that. but i would very much like to avoid that solution as it would complicate what i am doing.

Answer (score 0):

I found a tremendously helpful control in this question.

[Making a control transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358500/making-a-control-transparent)

the top answer has code for a control that supports real transparency even on top of video. this is perfect.

Comment: iam facing thesame problem. i try to add panel on top of vlc. but how do i set it to  transparent. because i have tried set tranparency color to the form and panel with same color. what i got is, its absolutely transparent (it means the display was my own desktop)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45710806/how-to-set-transparent-opacity-to-panel

Comment: So you do or you dont have a problem still? it sounds like you answered your own question from your wording, but it also sounds like your problem wasnt solved from your wording

Comment: solve it thanks :) , the comment above is because i set the form transparency key color same with panel color, therefore its absolutely display the desktop. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31656655/how-to-make-user-controls-transparent